# How to get values from nested JSON data?

Tags: php, json

Here's my JSON code:

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 2,
        "created": "2013-04-03T09:47:03Z",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "results": {
            "yctCategories": {
                "yctCategory": {
                    "score": "0.504762",
                    "content": "Computing"
                }
            },
            "entities": {
                "entity": [
                    {
                        "score": "0.902",
                        "text": {
                            "end": "19",
                            "endchar": "19",
                            "start": "0",
                            "startchar": "0",
                            "content": "Computer programming"
                        },
                        "wiki_url": "http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Computer_programming"
                    },
                    {
                        "score": "0.575",
                        "text": {
                            "end": "51",
                            "endchar": "51",
                            "start": "41",
                            "startchar": "41",
                            "content": "programming"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and below is my PHP code

```
$json_o = json_decode($json,true);
echo "Json result:</br>";
echo $json; // json
echo "</br></br>";
echo "Value result:</br>";
$result = array();
//$entity = $json_o['query']['results']['entities']['entity'];
foreach ($json_o['query']['results']['entities']['entity'] as $theentity)
 foreach ($theentity['text'] as $thetext){
    $result[] = $thetext['content'];
 }
print_r($result);
```

My expectation is to get the value of content in entity, which is "**Computer programming**" and "**programming**".

I already searching around, but still have found the solution yet.

The result of my PHP code is:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => C [5] => 5 [6] => 5 [7] => 4 [8] => 4 [9] => p )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your foreach to:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($json_o['query']['results']['entities']['entity'] as $theentity) {
    $result[] = $theentity['text']['content'];
}
print_r($result);
```

`$theentity['text']` is an array of keys => value. You can just access key `content` instead of looping through all of the entries.

Another way you could do it (though it is a poor choice) is:

```
foreach($theentity['text'] as $key => $value) {
    if( 'content' === $key ) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

I provide this second example to demonstrate why the original code did not work.

**Update**

To access other properties like the `yctCategories` just do something similar

```
$categories = array();
foreach ($json_o['query']['results']['yctCategories'] as $yctCategory) {
    $categories[] = $yctCategory['content'];
}
print_r($categories);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this loop

```
foreach ($json_o['query']['results']['entities']['entity'] as $theentity)
{
    $result[] = $theentity['text']['content'];
}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/tFxh1w

Output **Array ( [0] => Computer programming [1] => programming )**

Answer (score 0):

remove the second foreach and replace it with `$result[] = $theentity['text']['content'];`

using something like http://jsonlint.com/ might make it easier for you to see how the json is structured. alternatively just `var_dump` (or `print_r`) the output of your `json_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple code:

```
$array = $json_o['query']['results']['entities']['entity'];

foreach($array as $v){
  echo $v['text']['content'];
}
```

Comment: duplicating data unnecessarily, no reason to be inefficient here.

Comment: @RickBurgess ok, but provides more readability :) and performance when editing

Comment: @Akam thx for the clarification.. it gave me some other option in writing the code